# Only getting Your App Service app has been created - after deploying to azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

After I deploy a web api to azure, I get the screen:

```
Your App Service app has been created

Go to your app's Quick Start guide in the Azure portal to get started or read our deployment documentation.
```

I try to access some of the api/controller end points but then I get the message:

```
"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
```

Does this take a while to start on or shouldn't it work straight away?

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm getting the same

Comment: @Escobar5 - Hey, I think I have. I'm using VS2017 and I modified the installation to include the Azure SDK somewhere. Google it you'll find it. I published it and it's working.