# Deploy Django app to Azure VS2017 - custom python

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, azure

I've made a simple app with Django in Visual Studio 2017, utilizing the default template in Visual Studio (file - new - project - python - django web application). I've installed django PTVS through the azure portal and added a custom python extension. The app runs properly locally, but after i deploy it to Azure via Visual Studio, i can only access the page that shows:

`'Your App Service app has been created.'`

I've read several posts ([Deploy a simple VS2017 Django app to Azure - server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43506691/deploy-a-simple-vs2017-django-app-to-azure-server-error)) and followed the following tutorials: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service

My web.config looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="Python27_via_FastCGI" />
      <remove name="Python34_via_FastCGI" />
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\python361x64\python.exe|D:\home\python361x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="%SystemDrive%\home\site\wwwroot" />
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="DjangoWebProject2.wsgi.application()"/>
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="app.settings" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

UPDATE:

I managed to get it working, the problem was that it still kept using the env with python 3.4 and there seemed to be a package dependency that required a newer version of python I therefore changed the app settings as follows.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="myApp.wsgi.application"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot" />
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="myApp.settings" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\python362x86\python.exe|D:\home\python362x86\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Files" stopProcessing="true">
          <conditions>
            <add input="true" pattern="false" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Configure Python" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/static/.*" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="handler.fcgi/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi,any updates ?

Comment: @JayGong Sorry, I thought I already posted the results. So yes I managed to get it working, the problem seemed to be that it kept using the env with python 3.4 I therefore changed the app settings to use a newer python version.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for your replying.I summarized the issue in my answer. You could mark the answer for others' reference on the forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue, but failed. My Django app created & deployed by VS2017 to Azure WebApps and it works. There are some similar SO threads which have the same issue with yours.

1. [Only getting Your App Service app has been created - after deploying to azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134656/only-getting-your-app-service-app-has-been-created-after-deploying-to-azure)
2. [Django web app deploy in Azure via Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44355631/django-web-app-deploy-in-azure-via-visual-studio-2017)

You can follow the above threads to try again. Also you can refer to [the official tutorial for Django](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-ptvs-django-mysql) to create and deploy your django app to Azure, then to change your `web.config` to use the Python 3.6.1 extension.

Here is the content of my `web.config` file as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Generated web.config for Microsoft Azure. Remove this comment to prevent
     modifications being overwritten when publishing the project.
-->
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_HANDLER" value="django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()" />
    <add key="WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_ACTIVATE_THIS" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Scripts\activate_this.py" />
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.get_virtualenv_handler()" />
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot" />
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="JayGongDjango.settings" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\python361x64\python.exe|D:\home\python361x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Files" stopProcessing="true">
          <conditions>
            <add input="true" pattern="false" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Configure Python" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/static/.*" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="handler.fcgi/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

---

Just as summary , the issue is the project kept using the env with python 3.4.Just change it to the new version of python interpreter.

web.config settings:

```
<appSettings> 
  <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="myApp.wsgi.application"/> 
  <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/> 
  <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/> 
  <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot" /> 
  <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="myApp.settings" /> 
</appSettings>
```

Hope it helps.