# Using python 3.6 on azure app services - not working despite it is installed as extension

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-web-app-service, wagtail

I've got a challenge with deploying Django app (wagtail to be precise) to Azure Web Services using external Git repo (Bitbucket). I want to use Python 3.6.1, therefore I followed instructions at [Managing Python on Azure App Service manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service)

- I have python 3.6.1 extension installed and in place
- I created web.config file in root directory of my app (I checked and it is uploaded to the server)

However, deploy fails with message

```
Detecting Python runtime from runtime.txt
Unsupported runtime: python-3.6.1

Supported runtime values are:
python-2.7
python-3.4
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\66.61008.3066\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

My web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <!-- Django apps only -->
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule"
           scriptProcessor="D:\home\python361x64\python.exe|D:\home\python361x64\wfastcgi.py"
           resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Paths are ok, below is `ls` from Kudu console

```
D:\home\python361x64>ls
DLLs
Lib
Scripts
__pycache__
python.exe
python3.dll
python36.dll
pythonw.exe
sitecustomize.py
vcruntime140.dll
wfastcgi.py
```

It looks like the deployment process is not taking into account the web.config file that I have, or the python version that I've installed via extensions is not visible.

Could you please tell me where the possible issue could be?

Best regards,
Konrad

Comment: Familiar with building Docker images? Build your own (import from `python:3.6.3-jessie`) and deploy to App Service on a Linux worker. You'll be done in 15 minutes - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image

Comment: Thanks for your remark. Unfortunately I am not really keen on Docker, so, for now, I decided to go without it (I actually solved my issues and deployed the app). However, in future for sure I had to get more familiar with Docker as it is a really cool tool (I only used the already provided containers ;) )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a couple of hours of fighting, I finally managed to run this bastard as expected ;)

Thanks, @Jay Gong for your input as going step by step with this tutorial showed me a couple of things.

1. `runtime.txt` file, which I had in the root folder, was the first issue. As 3.6 version of python is installed via extensions, in fact, deployment process does not now that this v. exists (it "knows" only 2.7 and 3.4). So the first step was to get rid of this file.
2. When `runtime.txt` had been removed, deployment process has been using python 3.4 and was failing on installation one of the dependencies from `requirements.txt` file (probably because of the older version of python). So the next step was to add .skipPythonDeployment, to avoid automatic installation of requirements and install those manually by kudu console. In folder with our python env (in my case `D:\home\python361x64`) following command was launched
   `python.exe -m pip install --upgrade -r D:\home\site\wwwroot\requirements.txt`
   All dependencies were installed correctly.
3. After deploy, launching an app in a web browser showed message `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`. Next step was to gather more info about the issue, so I have added a few new lines in `web.config` file:

   ```
   ....
   <system.webServer>
   ....
       <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"></httpErrors>
   </system.webServer>
   <system.web>
       ....
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
   </system.web>
   ```

   Thanks to that, I was able to check what is causing the issue. In my case, it was a `WSGI_HANDLER` value in `web.config`. I set it to a correct value (for wagtail it was `<app_name>.wsgi.application` and then it started working.

Thank you guys for all your support.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing. It's a good reference for me. Have a nice day!

Comment: pitty you didnt say whats the correct path for the handler

Answer (score 3):

I tried to reproduce your issue but failed.I tried to deploy my own `django web app` to azure and it works.

You could refer to my steps and check if you you missed something.

***Step 1:*** Follow the [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-python) to create your azure web app.

***Step 2:*** Add Python extension.

[image]

***Step 3:*** Add `web.config` file and deploy your web app.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="<your project name>.wsgi.application"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\python361x64\python.exe|D:\home\python361x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Files" stopProcessing="true">
          <conditions>
            <add input="true" pattern="false" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Configure Python" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/static/.*" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="handler.fcgi/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

***Step 4:*** Install `pip plugin` in your `python extension environment`.

***Step 5:*** Install `django` module and other modules you want to use.

There are some similar SO threads you could refer to.

1. [Only getting Your App Service app has been created - after deploying to azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134656/only-getting-your-app-service-app-has-been-created-after-deploying-to-azure)
2. [Django web app deploy in Azure via Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44355631/django-web-app-deploy-in-azure-via-visual-studio-2017)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Jay, I'm confused about the `pip plugin`. Where is the `python extension environment`? I can't find it in the Azure interface.

Comment: @ChrisMay You could find it on the kudu after you installed the python extension environment.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the missing parts of Calfy answer.

```
<add key="WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_HANDLER" value="app.wsgi_app" />
<add key="WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_ACTIVATE_THIS" value="D:\home\python361x64\python.exe" />
<add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.get_venv_handler()"/>
```

app.wsgi_app is actually app.py in your folder and from what i understand it must be an wsgi app not regular python app.. (i also used cherrypy mod here) this sample app is copied somewhere from internet.

```
import sys
import cherrypy

class Hello(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.response_headers(headers=[('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    def index(self):
        message = """\
Hello Azure!
Python: {python_version}
CherryPy: {cherrypy_version}

More info: http://blog.cincura.net/id/233498
"""
        return message.format(python_version=sys.version, cherrypy_version=cherrypy.__version__)


wsgi_app = cherrypy.Application(Hello(), '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

    httpd = make_server('', 6600, wsgi_app)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```